# Accessing IP webcam streams

Tags: silverlight, rtsp, mjpeg

I have been asked to investigate having IP camera streams directly in the Silverlight application (running in browser). From what I can see this seems to mean I need to be able to handle RTSP streams and Motion JPEG streams. Both of which are not natively supported in Silverlight.

I found a library (http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/MJPEG-Decoder) for MJPEG decoding but it only supports OOB in Silverlight which is a problem.

I could only find commercial products for the RTSP but I also read that you can use the `MediaStreamSource` API to do almost any stream manually but information on how to do this in RTSP I couldn't find anywhere.

So how do you do it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Silverlight MediaElement? It basically provides windows media player as a Silverlight control and as far as I know it supports RTSP and motion JPEG. However, RTSP is a bit of an interoperation nightmare the windows media player implementation may not play RTSP from all sources. You should just be able to set the source property to the URL. If it fails to play the stream, as I said, it's probably an RTSP incompatibility.